# How would i assign Objects in a form to an array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, object, visual-studio-2012

I am attempting to check the text property of a button to determine if it does not contain anything in its text property.

I would do that like this:

```
 if (btn_1.Text != string.Empty && btn_2.Text != string.Empty && ETC...)
    MessageBox.Show("The game is a draw")
```

Checking all 9 buttons seems "inefficient" and tedious if I can just assign the buttons and their properties to an array where i would check them using a foreach statement.

The issue is that i cannot figure out how to do so even after scouring the internet.

I have this as my declaration:

```
 object[] buttonArray = new object[]{ btn_1, btn_2, btn_3, btn_4, btn_5, btn_6, btn_7, btn_8, btn_9 };
```

Obviously this is wrong, what would be the proper way to implement this array so that I can check the button's properties?

Comment: I don't see how this is inefficient, either way you are going to have to run the same checks to see if the text field is empty.

Comment: Instead of an `object` array, make it a `Button` array.

Comment: "Obviously this is wrong", no its fine, just make it an array of buttons

Comment: 'Button[] buttonArray = new Button[]{ btn_1, btn_2, btn_3, btn_4, btn_5, btn_6, btn_7, btn_8, btn_9 };'  This didn't work, I'm not sure why though.

Comment: well cause it just creates an array and doesn't do anything to check if button texts are empty...

Comment: @SethDev What do you mean by "didn't work"? Compile error? Exception?

Comment: It tells me a field initializer cannot reference a method, property, or object in the form. So the declaration is correct but i have something else incorrect. @romanoza Sorry, it is a compilation error.

Comment: You can access controls by name: `MyForm.Controls["btn_1"]`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Linq query

```
List<Button> buttonList = new List<Button>();

buttonList.Add(btn1);
.
..
...
..
buttonList.Add(btn9);

vsr result  = buttonList.All(x=>x.Text!=string.Empty);

if(result)
MessageBox.Show("The game is a draw");
```

or you can use object intializer instead of calling Add multiple times

```
    List<Button> buttonList = new List<Button>()
{
   btn1,
   btn2,
   ...
   btn9
};

    vsr result  = buttonList.All(x=>x.Text!=string.Empty);

    if(result)
    MessageBox.Show("The game is a draw");
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
using System.Linq;

.....

Button[] buttonArray = new Button[] {btn_1, btn_2, btn_3, btn_4, btn_5, btn_6, btn_7, btn_8, btn_9};
if(buttonArray.All(b => b.Text != string.Empty))
    MessageBox.Show("The game is a draw");
```

where
   btn_1..btn_9 are declared as:

```
Button btn_1, btn_2, btn_3, btn_4, btn_5, btn_6, btn_7, btn_8, btn_9;
```

Make sure the initialization of `buttonArray` is placed after the initializations of `btn_1`..`btn_9` to avoid creating the array of nulls.